# Клиент-серверное приложение для выполнения команды, написанной на клиенте, на хосте сервера. С чего начать? Что использовать?

Tags: javascript, c, клиент-сервер

Суть в том, что должен написать легковесный сервер (вес ~500кб ) под linux, на который с клиента отправляется команда, и та выполняется в терминале. С этой сферой дело не имел. Хочется знать с чего начать, что использовать для написания своей программы (готовые не подойдут, только если open source)?  Буду очень благодарен если поможете или объясните где и в чем я заблуждаюсь

Comment: получается, что  достаточно telnet сервера, а он и так есть в любом дистрибутиве линукса, ну или ssh

Comment: Да, это можно, но надо именно написать свмому. Плюс в стоковом наборе команд прошивки маршрутизатора отсутствуют перечисленные вами. Можно конечно самому реализовать telnet-сервер и клиент, но довольно сложновато

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно на C через сокеты отправлять текст(команду), а на сервере функцией system() выполнять то, что передал